# Steps involved to execute a COBOL program static calling a COBOL/DB2 subprogram

Tags: db2, cobol, jcl

I have a main program which is purely COBOL, and a COBOL-DB2 subprogram. I compiled both using a cobol-db2 compiler, return code is 4 (informational warning only). Then, I bind them both. Now I'm trying to execute the main program using a JCL DB2, however, it doesn't seem to be able to call the subprogram or even execute the run step.
This is my JCL DB2 to run the mainprog calling the subprog:

```
//GO       EXEC PGM=IKJEFT01,DYNAMNBR=20,REGION=4M,COND=(4,LT)  
//STEPLIB  DD   DSN=DSN910.DB9G.RUNLIB.LOAD,                    
//         DISP=SHR                                             
//         DD   DISP=SHR,DSN=DSN910.DB9G.SDSNEXIT               
//         DD   DISP=SHR,DSN=DSN910.SDSNLOAD                    
//         DD   DISP=SHR,DSN=ISP.SISPLOAD                       
//         DD   DISP=SHR,DSN=GDDM.SADMMOD                       
//SYSOUT   DD   SYSOUT=*                                        
//SYUDUMP  DD   SYSOUT=*                                        
//CEEDUMP  DD   SYSOUT=*                                        
//TRANFILE DD   DSN=PROJECT.ABC.TRANKSDS,DISP=SHR              
//MGMTREPT DD   DSN=PROJECT.ABC.MGMTREPT,                      
//         UNIT=SYSDA,DISP=(NEW,CATLG),                         
//         SPACE=(32,(3,3)),                                    
//         DCB=(RECFM=FB,LRECL=81,BLKSIZE=81)                         
//SYSPRINT DD   SYSOUT=*                       
//SYSTSPRT DD   SYSOUT=*                       
//SYSTSIN  DD   *                              
  DSN SYSTEM(DB9G)                             
  RUN PROGRAM(ABCREPRT) PLAN(DSNTIA91)         
  END                                          
/*
```

Then this is the SDSF of the JCL, return code = 0:

```
 NP   DDNAME   StepName ProcStep DSID 
      JESMSGLG JES2                 2 
      JESJCL   JES2                 3 
      JESYSMSG JES2                 4
```

Shouldn't GO stepname appear as well if it's a successful execution?

Answer (score 0):

I would at least expect a `READY` message on `//SYSTSPRT` if that step did start. So, yes there should be an entry for `SYSTSPRT` in that list. Did you look at the `OUTPUT` queue in SDSF to see if some output of your job went to this queue instead of the `HOLD` queue?

You could replace the `DSN` ... `END` sequence in `//SYSTSIN` with some TSO command, say `LISTA` and see if this produces some output.

Comment: There's now an entry for SYSTSPRT, ready message appeared which means the step started right? But there's no SYSOUT, SYSPRINT. I check the OUTPUT and HELD OUTPUT QUEUE as well, there's nothing there. I tried putting in the TSO command LISTA, still no output.

Comment: Having a `READY` message in `//SYSTSPRT` indeed confirms that the IKJEFT01 (i.e. TSO) started. If this is the only message, it didn't read any commands from `//SYSTSIN`. What do you expect to see on `//SYSOUT`, or `//SYSPRINT`? Can you post the complete JCL, and the complete output from the job?